# What are common materials that absorb near infrared radiation?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, infrared-radiation

I am running an experiment in my university lab where I want to compare with a sensor how much IR radiation gets transmitted in different scenarios. I need some (preferably common) materials that absorb near infrared radiation (about 3.1 microns). I found here that something white will do it like a piece of paper, but it did not give good results. I need to absorb as much IR as possible preferably in the cheapest way possible. Since my sensor is also small, the whole setup is pretty small. Therefore, I am looking for something that is small as well (like my paper example). Are there any options to this?

Comment: Black stuff in general, paper included.

Comment: https://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/blackest-is-the-new-black-scientists-have-developed-a-material-so-dark-that-you-cant-see-it-9602504.html

Comment: I tried black paper, but it did not work at all :(